# If $v(x)$ is a real $2\pi$ periodic function with $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(x)e^{inx}dx=0$ then prove $v=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> If $v(x)$ is a real Riemann Integrable $2\pi$ periodic function with $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(x)e^{inx}\mathbb dx=0$ for all integers $n$, then prove $v(x)=0\space\space\forall x\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

I am stuck on this question, with negligible progress. Please give some hints on how to start. Basically the question boils down to proving that $v(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ if $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(x)\cos nx\mathbb dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(x)\sin nx\mathbb dx=0$$for all integers (both positive and negative) $n$.

Comment: I don't think your question is suitable or right for $v(x)=\begin{cases}1, x=0\\0,x\neq0\end{cases}$ is one special case.

Comment: @KevinYang but in your example, $v(0) = 1 \neq 0 = v(2\pi)$. So it's not $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @kobe sorry, my definition is on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and you can extend it to $(-\infty,\infty)$. I mean this question doesn't say that $v(x)$ is continuous, so it can not be proved.

Comment: @KevinYang the result would be true if "$v(x) = 0\, \forall\, x\in [-\pi,\pi]$" is replaced by "$v(x) = 0$ for almost every $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$".

Comment: @kobe Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only conclude that $v = 0$ almost everywhere in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Fill in the details of the following argument. Since the Fourier coefficients of $v$ are zero, Parseval's theorem gives $\int_{-\pi}^\pi v^2(x)\, dx = 0$. Since $v^2$ is nonnegative,  $v^2(x) = 0$ for almost every $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. So $v(x) = 0$ for almost every $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: The actual question was to prove that if $f$ is a $2\pi$ periodic function such that $\hat{f(n)}$ is the $n-th$ Fourier coefficient then $\hat{f(-n)}=\bar{\hat{f(n)}}\implies f$ is real. I considered $f=u+iv$ and wanted to show that $v=0$.

Comment: You also need $f$ to be continuous, say on $[a,a + 2\pi]$. Then $\hat{f}(-n) - \overline{\hat{f}}(n) = 0$ for all $n$ $\implies$ $\int_a^{a + 2\pi} [f(x) - \overline{f(x)}] e^{-inx}\, dx = 0$ for all $n$. It follows from Parseval's theorem that $\int_a^{a + 2\pi} (f(x) -\overline{f(x)})^2\, dx = 0$. Since $(f - \bar{f})^2$ is nonnegative and continuous on $[a,a+2\pi]$, we deduce $f(x) - \overline{f(x)} = 0$ for all $x \in [a,a + 2\pi]$. Hence $f = \bar{f}$, i.e., $f$ is real.

Comment: No it is not given that $f$ is continuous, just given $f$ is riemann integrable i.e. continuous a.e.

Comment: If $f$ were continuous then your answer would be suitable and correct.

Comment: Without the continuity assumption, the result is false.