# Is the condition sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, periodic-functions

I am stuck on the following problem:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be **continuous** and $2\pi$-periodic and $n$ be a positive integer. If for any integer $p \in [0,n-1]$,
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \cos(pt)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \sin(pt)\,\mathrm{d}t=0,$$
then is it true that $f$ has at least $2n$ roots on $[0,2\pi]$?

I tried to prove the problem using induction. $p=0$ is easy , but $p=1$ is giving me a hard time.

Edit: After the comment of Dear Dunham , it's seems that we need both integral to be equal to zero , in other to work , in that case  we have the form : 
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) e^{ipt} \mathrm{d}t=0$$   , 
Now it looks like the trigonometric version of [Prove that $f$ has $m+1$ zeros if $\int_{a}^{b} x^nf(x)dx=0$ for all $n\le m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086057/prove-that-f-has-m1-zeros-if-int-ab-xnfxdx-0-for-all-n-le-m?rq=1)

**Edit:**  I made some progress with the new version of the question in the case $f$ is not identicaly $0$ , and proved $M \geq n$ , where $M$ is the number of zeros of $f$ as follow :
Let $(T_{n})$ the sequence of Tchebychev polynomial , $\cos(nt)=T_{n}(\cos(t))$ and $\deg(T_{n})=n$ . hence $(T_{0},...,T_{n-1})$ is a basis of $R_{n-1}[X]$ ,$0\leq a_{1}<a_{2}<... <a_{m}\leq \pi \leq a_{m+1}<..<a_{p}$ the zeros of $f$ and suppose that $p\leq n-1$  .
For $i \in [1,m-1]$ such that $a_{i}<x<a_{i+1}$ since cosinus is decreasing in  $[0,\pi[$ then $b_{i+1}=\cos(a_{i+1}) < \cos(x) < b_{i}=\cos(a_{i})$  ,
on the other hand, for $j \in [m ,p-1]$ we have $c_{j}=\cos(a_{j}) < \cos(x) < c_{j+1}=\cos(a_{j+1})$  since here cosine is increasing in $[\pi ,2 \pi]$. 
We have then $(d_{n})$ constructed from $(b_{n})$ and $(c_{n})$ such that :  $\forall x \in [0,2\pi]-J :  f(x)  \Pi_{i=1}^{p} (\cos(x)-d_{i}) > 0$ where 
$J=\{a_{1},a_{2},....,a_{p}, d_{1},...,d_{p}\}$ , the polynomial $P(x)=\Pi_{i=1}^{p}(x-d_{i})$ is of degree at most $n-1$ , hence we have $(t_{i})$ such that:  $P(\cos(t))=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} t_{i}T_{i}(\cos(t))$ by linearity of the integral, we conclude that : $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t)P(t)=0$ hence $f(x)=0$ For any  $x \in [0,2\pi]-J$ , hence by continuity $f=0$ every where, contradiction .

I feel that I can improve this solution , by a better choice of the sequence of polynomial , one that also include the orthoganility with the familly $\sin(pt)$ $p \in [[0,n-1]]$ this information is critical to improve the bound , any help ? thank you a lot .

Comment: I probably do not understand your statement correctly. Your induction should go on $n$, right? For $n=1$ (then you only have $p=0$) you should, according to the statement have at least $2$ zeros. But the only thing you get from the condition is $\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt=0$ which enforces only one zero. What do I miss?

Comment: @mickep , thank your interest ,  here is the details of my argument for $n=1$ , because $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic and continuous $f$ must vanish at least $2$ times  ; suppose that there is only one $u \in [0, 2\pi[$ such that $f(u)=0$ , then $f$ have different signe in $[0,u[$ and $[u,2\pi]$ by continuity ;  then  Wlog $f(0)> 0$ and $f(2\pi) < 0$ but this a contradiction with the fact that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$

Comment: I see. Did not think about the periodicity. You should probably add that $f$ is continuous, though.

Comment: oh yes  i am sorry , didn't notice that I missed it . I edited  thank you

Comment: Similar one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650153/roots-of-a-function-with-first-fourier-coefficients-equal

Comment: After the edit, it is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212531/if-vx-is-a-real-2-pi-periodic-function-with-int-pi-pivxeinxd?rq=1

Comment: here the same technique doesn't work

Comment: In your proof using Chebyshev polynomials, how do you construct $(d_i)$'s  presumably distinct from $(b_i)$ and $(c_i)$? I do not think you can due to $\cos$ being not an injection from $[0,2\pi)\to [-1,1]$.

Comment: suppose wlog in $]a_{i} , a_{i+1}[ $ , $f> 0$    if $i \leq m-1$  then we choose  $d_{i}=b_{i+1}$ then $(\cos(x)-d_{i}) > 0$ in $]a_{i},a_{i+1}[$  ,  if $i\geq m$ , we choose $d_{i}=c_{i}$   then we also have $(\cos(x)-d_{i}) >0$ , in each interval $]a_{i},a_{i+1}[$ we choose $d_{i}$ such that $f$ and $\cos(x)-d_{i}$  have the same signe .

Comment: That does not work for $c_k\in(b_i,b_{i+1})$ with all other $c_k$'s outsider of $(b_i,b_{i+1})$. As $x$ increases from $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$, $\cos(x)$ decreases from $b_i$ to $b_{i+1}$ through $c_k$, the sign of the product $(\cos(x)-b_i)(\cos(x)-b_{i+1})(\cos(x)-c_k)$ flips while the signs of all other terms in $P(\cos(x))$ remain unchanged. So you will not have $f(x)P(\cos(x))>0,\, \forall x$ and the construction does not work. It is due to $cos$ being not an injection from $[0,2\pi)→[−1,1]$.

Comment: $(b_{i})$ is descrasing Dear Hans , Ah you mean that we may $c_{k} \in (b_{i+1},b_{i})$ ? for some $i$

Comment: Yes, I mean the latter. But the key is that $c_k$ being in between $b_{i+1}$ and $b_i$ will flip the sign and make the method fail. By the way, please put @Hans in your reply so that I get notified.

Comment: @Hans , thank you . Don't you think that we can improve the construction ,to make it work ,  isolating the points   $c_{i} \in (b_{i+1},b_{i})$ and improving the construction for them  ?

Comment: I would very much like it to work since I think this is an attractive route. Perhaps the addition of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind may help resolve the ambiguity. But I do not see how, at least yet.

Comment: There is another proof using a heat equation. I will write it out when I have time.

Comment: @Hans , thank you a lot , heat equation , very interesting .

Answer (score 6):

**original problem**

If $f(t)=\cos(t)+\sin(t)$ then there are only 2 zeros, yet the conditions are true for any value of $n$.

**Revised problem: proof sketch**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $2\pi$ periodic with $M\in \mathbb{N}$ zeros. Also, suppose $\int f(t)e^{ipt}dt=0$ for $|p|<n$.

Define $f_k$ to be the $k$th zero mean antiderivative of $f$.

Since $f_1$ has $M$ critical values, $f_1$ has at most $M$ zeros. Similarly, $f_k$ has at most $M$ zeros for all $k$.

Now, $f_1$ has a convergent Fourier series
\begin{equation}
f_1(t) = \sum_{\ell\geq n} a_\ell \cos(\ell t) +b_\ell \sin(\ell t)
\end{equation}

Then $f_{4L+1}$ has Fourier series
\begin{equation}
f_{4L+1}(t) = \sum_{\ell\geq n} 
\frac{a_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \cos(\ell t) 
+\frac{b_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \sin(\ell t)
\end{equation}

For $L$ sufficiently large, all terms except the first
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_n}{n^{4L}} \cos(n t)
+\frac{b_n}{n^{4L}} \sin(n t)
\end{equation}
are negligible. This first term has $2n$ zeros, so $f_{4L+1}$ has at least $2n$ zeros. Thus $M\geq 2n$.

**Definition:**

Given a continuous $2\pi$-periodic function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with mean 0, we can find an antiderivative
\begin{equation*}
\widetilde G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt.
\end{equation*}
Then the mean zero antiderivative of $g$ is
\begin{equation*}
G(x) = \widetilde G(x) - \int_0^{2\pi} \widetilde{G}(t)dt.
\end{equation*}
By the $k$th mean zero antiderivative, we mean $f_1$ is the mean zero antiderivative of $f$, $f_2$ is the mean zero antiderivative of $f_1$, and so on.

**Proposition:** 
In the series, 
\begin{equation}
f_{4L+1}(t) = \sum_{\ell\geq n} 
\frac{a_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \cos(\ell t) 
+\frac{b_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \sin(\ell t)
\end{equation}
for sufficiently large $L$, all terms except the first are neglibible.

**Proof:** 
 WLOG assume $a_n$ or $b_n$ is nonzero. Note that 
\begin{equation}
a_n \cos(n t)
+b_n \sin(n t)
\end{equation}
has $2n$ zeros and $2n$ extrema. The absolute value of the extrema is $\sqrt{|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2}$. Therefore, we shall make $L$ large enough so that the sum of the other terms is at most $\frac{\sqrt{|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2}}{2n^{4L}}$. We have $|a_{\ell}|\le \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{2\pi}|\cos(\ell x)f(x)|dx\le \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|dx$ and the same bound for $|b_{\ell}|$, $\forall\ell$. The terms are bounded as follows
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{\ell\geq n+1} 
\frac{a_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \cos(\ell t) 
+\frac{b_\ell}{\ell^{4L}} \sin(\ell t)\right|
&\leq
2\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
\sum_{\ell\geq n+1} 
\frac{1}{\ell^{4L}} \\
&\leq
2\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
+
\left(
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{4L}}
+
\sum_{\ell\geq n+2} 
\frac{1}{\ell^{4L}} 
\right)\\
&\leq
2\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
\left(
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{4L}}
+
\int_{n+1}^{\infty}
x^{-4L}
\right)\\
&=
2\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
\left(
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{4L}}
+
\frac{1}{(4L-1)(n+1)^{4L-1}}
\right)\\
&\leq
4\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{4L-1}}
\end{align*}
Now, we just have to show that 
\begin{equation*}
4\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{4L-1}}
\leq
\frac{\sqrt{|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2}}{2n^{4L}}
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
\frac{8n\max_{\ell>n }
\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}}
{\sqrt{|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2}}
\leq
\left(
\frac{n+1}{n}
\right)^{4L-1}
\end{equation*}
The left-hand side is constant, while the right-hand side diverges to $\infty$ as $L\rightarrow \infty$. Hence the result is true for some $L$.

**Proposition:** 
Suppose $f$ has $M\in \mathbb{N}$ zeros. Then
$f_k$ cannot have more zeros than $f$ for all $k$.

**Proof:** 
Consider $f_1$ as a differentiable function on the circle $\mathbb{T}$.  The derivative of $f_1$ is $f$, which has $M\in \mathbb{N}$ zeros. Since $f$ is continuous, the derivative of $f_1$ is defined everywhere, so the only critical values of $f_1$ are the zeros of $f$. Let $t_0$ and $t_1$ be any two consecutive zeros of $f$. Then $f_1$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on $[t_0,t_1]$. Hence $f_1$ has at most one zero on this interval. There are $M$ pairs of consecutive zeros of $f$. Hence $f_1$ has at most $M$ zeros. A similar argument applies to $f_2$ and so on.

Comment: you are right thank you  a lot , it's seems that we need both integral to be equal to zero .

Comment: Dear @Dunham , do you mean by the k-th zero mean antiderivative , $f_{k+1}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f_{k}(x) dx$ ?

Comment: @ oty I added a comment to clarify

Comment: "Since $f_1$ has $M$ critical values, $f_1$ has at most $M$ zeros." This is false. $f_1$ has at most $M+1$ zeros. So it does not follow that $M\ge 2n$.

Comment: @hans can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: $x^2-1$. Number of critical points $=1$, number of zeros $=2$.

Comment: @hans that function is not 2 pi periodic with a continuous derivative

Comment: OK. It would have been nice if you mention those two properties in that same sentence. The terms in the Fourier series beyond the first is "negligible" refers to the ratio of the sum of the remaining Fourier series to $\frac{\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2}}{n^{4L}}$ being arbitrarily uniformly small for all $t$ for large enough $L$, right? While this is intuitive and "natural", how would you prove it rigorously?

Comment: Nice. +1. The existence of $\max_{\ell>n }\{|a_\ell|,|b_\ell|\}$ needs to be justified. I took the liberty and added the one sentence proof. Hope you do not mind. Otherwise, I apologize.

Comment: Not at all, it's certainly worth noting

Comment: @Dunham , wonderfull solution , please , I don't understand why , if the others terms are '' negligible '', can make us conclude that the number of zeros, is at least the number of zeros of the first one ?

Comment: @oty there are two bounds here. 1) $f_k$ has no more zeros than $f$ and 2) $f_k$ has at least $2n$ zeros. Which part is unclear?

Comment: @Dunham the second part , $f_{k}$ has at least $2n$ zeros,  in particular this part in your proof  : '' This first term has $2n$ zeros , so $f_{k}$ has at least $2n$ zeros ''  . Thank you a lot .

Comment: @oty I added a proposition to explain

Comment: Dear @Dunham  , it wasn't the part I do not understand , I have trouble with this Line in your proof  :"" This first term has $2n$ zeros, so $f_{4L+1}$ has at least $2n$ zeros""

Comment: @oty that was addressed by the first proposition. Is there a point of that proof that is unclear?

Comment: @Dunham , Oh I think I unterstand now  , do you mean by the first term ''$f_{1}$'' ? , I was thinking you meant the first term of the  $\sum_{l\geq n} $ in fourier series and that confused me

Comment: @oty, I do mean the first term of the series

Comment: @Dunham , now I am confused , for me it is like saying : if $h=f+g$ and $g=o(f)$ if $f$ has $2n$ zeros then $h$ have at least $2n$ zeros .

Comment: @oty that's exactly it. The Maxima and minima of the first term are too large for the remaining terms to overcome. Hence there must be a zero between the consecutive extrema

Answer (score 0):

I provide a new solution here for someone who is interested.

**WLOG**, assume $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)\neq 0$(if not, just find a $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)\neq 0$ and do the transform $g(x)=f(x-\pi+x_0$).

Since $f(x)$ is continuous and periodic, there are only even points to change the sign of $f(x)$. Let these points to be 
$$
x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{2k}. 
$$
Then construct a function
$$
g(x)=\left(\sin \frac{x-x_1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\sin \frac{x-x_2}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\sin \frac{x-x_{2k}}{2}\right).
$$
Then we get 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d} x>0. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
It can be rewritten as
\begin{align}g(x)= &\left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x_1}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x_1}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x_2}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x_2}{2}\right)\\
&\cdots \left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x_{2k}}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x_{2k}}{2}\right)\\
=&f_1(\cos x)\sin x+f_2(\cos x)\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are polynomials and $\text{deg}f_1=k-1, \text{deg}f_2=k$. These two terms can be written as
\begin{equation}
f_1(\cos x)\sin x = a_k \sin kx + a_{k-1}\sin (k-1)x+\cdots+a_1\sin x + a_0\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_2(\cos x) = b_k \cos kx + b_{k-1}\cos (k-1)x+\cdots+b_1\cos x + b_0.\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
You can prove it by induction(see the notation below). If degree $k\leq n$, we get
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
by using the condition of the problem.
It controdicts to the equation \eqref{1}. Hence $k\geq n+1$ and the number of roots of $f(x)$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ is at least $2n+2$.

---

**Notation**: Assume for any $k<n$, we have
\begin{equation}
f_1(\cos x)\sin x = a_k \sin kx + a_{k-1}\sin (k-1)x+\cdots+a_1\sin x + a_0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_2(\cos x) = b_k \cos kx + b_{k-1}\cos (k-1)x+\cdots+b_1\cos x + b_0
\end{equation}
for all $ f_1, f_2\in \mathbb{R}_k[x]$. 
Then for all $ g_1, g_2\in\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ , you can extract a $\cos x$ and write them as
$$
g_1(\cos x)\sin x = \cos x(a_{n-1} \sin (n-1)x + a_{n-2}\sin (n-2)x+\cdots+a_1\sin x + a_0)
$$
$$
g_2(\cos x) = \cos x(a_{n-1} \cos (n-1)x + a_{n-2}\cos (n-2)x+\cdots+a_1\cos x + a_0).
$$
Then use the formula
$$
\cos\alpha\sin\beta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin(\beta+\alpha)+\sin(\beta-\alpha)\right]
$$
and
$$
\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos(\beta+\alpha)+\cos(\beta-\alpha)\right].
$$